# make sum of one column and join it with another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I want one query that gets sum of table 2 (addonAmount) column and combine it with table 1

table 1: `subscriptions`

```
+-------+--------+-------------+
| subId | userId | subDuration |
+-------+--------+-------------+
|    80 |   4607 | 6           |
|    81 |   4607 | 12          |
|    82 |   4608 | 18          |
+-------+--------+-------------+
```

table 2: `subscriptionAddons`

```
+---------+-------+-------------+
| addonId | subId | addonAmount |
+---------+-------+-------------+
|      15 |    80 | 4           |
|      16 |    80 | 2           |
+---------+-------+-------------+
```

Query I used:

```
SELECT subscriptions.*, subscriptionAddons.addonAmount
FROM subscriptions LEFT JOIN subscriptionAddons
ON subscriptions.subId = subscriptionAddons.subId;
```

what I want

```
+-------+--------+-------------+------------+
| subId | userId | subDuration |addonAmount |
+-------+--------+-------------+------------+
|    80 |   4607 | 6           |6           |
|    81 |   4607 | 12          |NULL        |
|    82 |   4608 | 18          |NULL        |
+-------+--------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by the columns that define a record and sum the column you want as result.

```
SELECT s.subId, s.userId, s.subDuration, sum(sa.addonAmount) as addonAmount
FROM subscriptions s LEFT JOIN subscriptionAddons sa
    ON s.subId = sa.subId
GROUP BY s.subId, s.userId, s.subDuration;
```